# How to identify if a project is downloaded project in xcode?

Tags: xcode

If a project is downloaded, how to change the setting so that it will look like a fresh project made. I have doubt people ca understand if project is downloaded or not.

I have to submit to my client and i dont have much time to develop. Can anyone tell me how to apply setting for downloaded project in order to make it appear a fresh one.Please suggest! **I'm using Xcode 6.1 Version.**

Comment: Please, explain yourself better. What do you mean when you say a "downloaded project", or "a fresh project"?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking - what are you seeing and what do you expect to see?

Comment: web080 - I have downloaded a project and I want to be sure that client dont let know I have downloaded.. Tell me first how will you get to know if the project is downloaded or not...?

Comment: Charloe Scott - I have a project which is downloaded. And my client should not get to know that i have downloaded this project... are there any setting in xcode which clearly shows that i have downloaded a project?

Answer (score 0):

Check what the team and bundle identifiers are set to, as well as the contents of the Info.plist.

Also check **very carefully** the license agreement of the project you downloaded and make sure you are legally allowed to re-use, modify and re-distribute it.

Especially if it is for commercial gain.